# Identifying groups of individuals if conditional occurence in one of them (next)

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, plyr

I come back to a previous question/post for which i got nice suggestions, but need an additional push : the idea is to create a binary variable which takes a value conditionnally to the individual status of any of related family members. This value is shared by all members of the same family. i put again a reproducive example:

```
      family <- factor(rep(c("001","002","003"), c(10,8,15)),levels=c("001","002","003"), labels=c("001","002","003"), ordered=TRUE)
      sx <- c(1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2)
      ag <- c(22,8,4,2,55,9,44,65,1,7,32,2,2,1,6,9,18,99,73,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,18,11,22,33)
      st <- factor(rep(c("a","b","c"),11))
      DF <- data.frame(family, ag,sx,st)  ; DF
```

One nice trick proposed by @Psidom allowed me to create this new variable `NoMan`, taking value `1`for all individuals from a family which does not include any man older than 16:

```
      DF <- ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +!any(sx == 1 & ag > 16)) ; DF ## works well !!
```

I am now trying to add another condition related to the age : `NoMan`also would equal `1`whenever any of the Male family members older than 16 has "a" or "b" as the attribute for the factor `st`. i tried the following but this did not work:

```
      DF <- ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = !any(sx == 1 & ag > 16) |
                                            all(sx == 1 & ag > 16 & st=="a") |
                                            all(sx == 1 & ag > 16 & st=="b")) ; DF
```

Any clue about the reason family 001 does not take the value `1`as `NoMan`? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with the following:

```
DF <- ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +!any((sx == 1 & ag > 16) & 
    ((sx == 1 & ag > 16 & st != "a") & (sx == 1 & ag > 16 & st != "b"))))
```

Or use a simplified one

```
 DF <- ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +!any(sx == 1 & ag > 16 
                                           & (st != "a" & st != "b")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work but i am not sure i understand it (and i would like to) : in your first proposition, which i prefer,  the function `+!any(` will first identify families without any man >16  `(sx == 1 & ag > 16)`which is fine, but then `+!any(` also applies to the second expression no? i would expect it to give the value `1`to all members NOT having ANY man>16 with `st=="a" ` or `st=="b" ` ?

Comment: Thank you @Darshan ! i understand better, this is not an easy one! i could check that this is working by using a slightly different `DF` : `family <- factor(rep(c("001","002","003","004"), c(10,8,15,3)), levels=c("001","002","003","004"), labels=c("001","002","003","004"), ordered=TRUE)
sx <- c(2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1)
ag <- c(22,8,4,2,55,9,44,65,1,7,32,2,2,1,6,9,18,99,73,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,18,11,22,33,19,5,19)
st <- factor(rep(c("a","b","c"),12))
DF <- data.frame(family, ag,sx,st)  ; DF `